# How can you make Twilio Webchat a full screen window?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to style the Twilio webchat sample so that it doesn't appear as a page intermodal and instead displays content at 100% width and height. I've gotten most of the way there:

[image]

However I'm not sure how to remove the expand/collapse buttons or have the chat auto initialise the chat on load. In essence the main question is: how can I use Webchat as a full-screen utility instead of a pop-up?

Comment: please can you share how to made it like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To have the chat auto initialise on load you should [trigger the `startEngagement` action](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/webchat/actions) when the chat has loaded. I think you can do that with:

```js
FlexWebChat.Actions.invoke("startEngagement");
```

The expand/collapse button is known as the EntryPoint. [You can style it, as it is a themable object](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/webchat/theming#webchat-ui-components-and-themable-objects), but you don't have the option to show/hide it. The available theming options are:

```
        EntryPoint: {
            Container: {
                backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to top, ${colors.defaultButtonColor}, ${colors.defaultButtonColor})`,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                color: "#ffffff",
                "&:hover": {
                    backgroundColor: colors.buttonHoverColor,
                    backgroundBlendMode: "color",
                }
            }
        }
```

You can also [remove components](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/components#syntax-for-remove-method), but you need the component key.